# What are XTRA, YOPQ, YTLC, etc. in CSS?

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

I'm reading a blog on [Roboto Flex font](https://material.io/blog/roboto-flex) which is a variable font, and I see mentions of

> - Parametric Counter Width (***XTRA*** in CSS)
> - Parametric Thin Stroke (***YOPQ*** in CSS)
> - Parametric Lowercase Height (***YTLC*** in CSS)

etc.

What are **XTRA**, **YOPQ**, **YTL**, etc. in CSS? What do they stand for?
I have never seen these properties before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They're [`font-variation-settings`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-4/#font-variation-settings-def) See [Get started with variable fonts in CSS](https://www.creativebloq.com/features/get-started-with-variable-fonts-in-css#13-more-variables) for an example of their use.

They can be defined in and be specific to the individual font.

Answer (score 1):

These are custom variation axes used in the Roboto Flex font. The blog you pointed to describes what each controls in the font.

The variable font format is defined in the [OpenType spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/otvaroverview). A variable font has one or more axes of design variation, and each axis is identified with a four-letter tag. The OpenType spec allows for "registered" axes, which have conventional definitions that all implementers can recognize, or custom tags that are foundry-specific. Registered axis tags use lowercase letters; foundry-defined axes use uppercase letters.

So, XTRA, YOPQ, etc. are variation axis tags defined by Google. The reference to "in CSS" is that the font parameters can be specified in CSS using the axis tags in conjunction with `font-variation-settings`, as mentioned in the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this great article that explains the font-variation-settings specific to [Roboto Flex](https://web.dev/variable-fonts/)